# Supressing GUI?

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, ubuntu

I am trying to run a plugin designed for [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/) using Java. For this I am using a command like this:

```
/home/x/jre1.6.0_14/bin/java -Dazureus.config.path=/home/x/plugin_directory -Dfile.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 -classpath /home/x/P/lib/swtgraphics2d.jar:/home/x/P/lib/Azureus2.jar:/home/x/P/lib/swt.jar org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main
```

The problem with this is that the launch is failing with an error:

```
changeLocale: *Default Language* != English (United States). Searching without country..
changeLocale: Searching for language English in *any* country..
changeLocale: no message properties for Locale 'English (United States)' (en_US), using 'English (default)'
Invoking main failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.launcher.MainExecutor$1.run(MainExecutor.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3910)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:470)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.<init>(SWTThread.java:84)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.createInstance(SWTThread.java:59)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.Initializer.<init>(Initializer.java:110)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.<init>(Main.java:88)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.main(Main.java:255)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "MainRunner" java.lang.SecurityException: VM exit operation prohibited
    at org.gudy.azureus2.core3.security.impl.SESecurityManagerImpl$2.checkExit(SESecurityManagerImpl.java:274)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.exit(Unknown Source)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.launcher.MainExecutor$1.run(MainExecutor.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am sure that this is happening because I am running the program on a terminal. Is there a way to supress the GUI or let the program think that the GUI was spawned successfully? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuze can be run headless, using the [Console UI](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Console_UI)

Comment: For some reason, when I try to do this, one of the plugins that I want working is not working anymore... I am not sure why that could be happening...

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the DISPLAY environment variable in your terminal before running:

```
export DISPLAY=<IP address>:0.0
```

Where  is the address of your host (or its hostname).

If you aren't running under a GUI at all, you'll have to run a virtual frame buffer. Xvfb is the one I've used in the past. Just make sure it's installed: `sudo apt-get xvfb` Then execute the following commands before running your app:

```
Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 &

export DISPLAY=:1
```

Then run the app..

Comment: I just realize I may have misinterpreted your comment that you were using a "barebones terminal from Ubuntu". Are you not using a GUI at all?

Comment: Thanks... Yes. I am not using a GUI at all. This is a remote ssh. In addition, when I use the Xvfb command, it keeps giving me "error opening security policy file /usr/lib/xserver/SecurityPolicy" and never allows azureus to start.

Comment: Pass xvfb the location of your X SecurityPolicy file using the `-sp` parameter. You're running Ubuntu, so it's probably at `/etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy`. So, the modified command line would look like: `Xvfb :1 -ac -sp /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy -screen 0 1024x768x8 &`

Answer (score 1):

You can start a virtual display via vnc and let java use this.
(See for example: http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/12/13/vnc-to-a-headless-ubuntu-box.aspx)

There are also headless parameters for certain libraries, so they run without a display like:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

(This needs to be appended to the java command line call or somewhere in the config, depending on the framework you are using)

Comment: Oh.. I'm not using vnc but rather a barebones terminal from Ubuntu. Do you mind being a little more specific? I'm afraid I did not get your answer but thanks for your time though.